# resizing text window on python

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

here is the code that I´m working with, I´m a newbie to coding so, forgive any mistake

```
# import required modules
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd

# Create an instance of tkinter frame
window = Tk()

# Set the size of the tkinter window
window.geometry("1920x1080")

# Load data from source
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\rrios\Downloads\BOTAS1.xlsx")
df = df.fillna('')  
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

# Extract number of rows and columns
n_rows = df.shape[0]
n_cols = df.shape[1]

# Extracting columns from the data and 
#creating text widget with some
# background color
column_names = df.columns
i=0
for j, col in enumerate(column_names):
    text = Text(window, width=16, height=1, bg = "#9BC2E6")
    text.grid(row=i,column=j)
    text.insert(INSERT, col)

# Dictionary for storing the text widget
# references
cells = {}


# adding all the other rows into the grid
for i in range(n_rows):
    for j in range(n_cols):
        text = Text(window, width=16, height=1)
        text.grid(row=i+1,column=j)
        text.insert(INSERT, df.loc[i][j])
        cells[(i,j)] = text

def do_something():
    """
    When user clicks the "Save" button, modified data
    will be saved in excel file
    """
    for i in range(n_rows):
        for j in range(n_cols):
                if df.loc[i][j] != cells[(i,j)].get("1.0", "end-1c"):
                    df.loc[[i],column_names[j]] = cells[(i,j)].get("1.0", "end-1c")
    df.to_excel(r"C:\Users\rrios\Downloads\BOTAS1.xlsx", index=FALSE)

save_button = Button(
    window, height = 2,
    width = 16,
    text ="Save",
    command = lambda:do_something())
save_button.grid(row=0,column = 7)
window.mainloop()
```

so, I have this code that i´m working with, I´d like to instead of setting the text window size to 16, as shown on code, make it so it resizes according to the text it contains, is it possible? how do I do that?

Comment: Use `width=len(col)`. Or simply use `Entry` widget: `text = Entry(window, width=0, bg="#9BC2E6")`.

Comment: that´s cool, the problem is that I am loading a whole table from an excel file, not individual columns, so if i put those, it cuts all text, except the one from the smaller column (all the others get it´s size)

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what your problem is.

Comment: https://imgur.com/xsIQDXN here is how the app looks, i´d like the columns to resize automatically acording to the text it contains

Comment: as it is now, it cuts out the text on "descrição do item" row

Comment: You need to set `width=len(str(df.loc[i][j]))` when creating those cells. Also set `sticky="ew"` in `.grid(...)` on all the text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `width=len(str(df.loc[i][j]))` when creating those cells.

Also set `sticky="ew"` in `.grid(...)` on all the text boxes.

Answered by: acw1668